# Проход по списку std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, std-list, unique-ptr

Как пройти по списку, содержащему `std::unique_ptr`, используя следующий синтаксис:

```
for ( auto i : myList )
```

Comment: А если `auto&`?

Comment: Работает, большое спасибо.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Смотрите, `unique_ptr` не копируется (иначе уникальность указателя нарушилась бы). Поэтому вам нужно итерировать не по *копиям* ваших элементов массива, а по ссылкам на них.

```
for (auto& i : myList) ...
```